# Drawing a simplex/diagram with crossings

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, intersections

I'm trying to come up with a way of drawing a simplex and handling crossings via loops in the most naive way possible: for every possible pair of lines,

1. find the intersection point
2. draw the first line
3. draw a white circle at the intersection point
4. draw the second line

I'm using the `intersections` library, which gets me 90% of the way there, but it's throwing an the error `` Package pgf Error: No shape named `intersection-1' is known. ``, which I assume is because my code generates lines (of length 0) which don't intersect.

Is there some way of making sure `(\x)!=(\y) && (\z)!=(\w)`? Or is there a better way to generate simplices?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (2,0);
\coordinate (C) at (2.5,1);
\coordinate (D) at (0.5,1);
\foreach \x in {A,B,C,D}{
 \foreach \y in {A,B,C,D}{
   \foreach \z in {A,B,C,D}{
     \foreach \w in {A,B,C,D}{
      \draw[name path=line 1] (\x) -- (\y);
      \path[name path=line 2] (\z) -- (\w);
      \fill[white,name intersections={of=line 1 and line 2, by={intpt}}] (intpt) circle[radius=2pt];
      }
    }
  }
\draw[fill=black] (\x) circle[radius=2pt];
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Plain TeX would allow you to do `\unless\ifx\x\y \unless\ifx\z\w <x != \y> && \z != \w> \fi\fi` but if you would use numbers instead of letters we could construct the loops better from the start. (This is also possible with letters but makes it much more complicated, especially if you have more than 26 points.) Isn't the only non-trivial intersection the one in the middle? Do you really need to find the intersection that lies on the corner, i.e. one of the already named coordinates?

Comment: There's another problem. You can't provide more `by`s than there are actual intersections. A safe approach would be to use `total=\t` and then do something with `(intersection-1)` if `\t` > 0. (Possible bug?)

Comment: Re: your first question, this is just a simple example. In practice I have a varying number of vertices (from 3 to 10). I'd be happy to use numbers if you think it would be easier. No, I don't really care about intersections at the corners -- that's just a byproduct of the (really inefficient) set of nested loops I came up with.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about using ```total```; that worked! I also discovered that the vertices were being colored, but that my loop was accidentally coloring over them.